# INSERT SELECT query not working

Tags: php, mysql

What's wrong with my code? It's echoing FAILED, I don't know why. However, it does not output an error as I would expect.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'posharrison');

$b=$_POST['barcode'];

$query  = "INSERT INTO produtcs
            SELECT * FROM item_code WHERE code = $b";
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query);

if ($result) {

    echo "success";

    }
 else {

    echo "FAILED!".die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: You really have a table called `produtcs`??

Comment: is `$b` a number? If it's a string you need quotes around it

Comment: What is the output of `mysqli_error()` ?

Comment: Do the columns match between the `produtcs` [sic] table and the `item_code` table

Comment: There may be unique key collision or mismatch in columns

Comment: When $b is a string, you must use it like this: '$b'. Are you sure you don't see any MySQL errors? Is your mysql connection correct?

Comment: You have to use `mysqli_error()` to get the error. (You forgot the `i`)

Comment: i saw the error .. thanks for the answers.. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 this is the error says..

Comment: INSERT INTO produtcs values(SELECT * FROM item_code WHERE code = $b);

Comment: (As per your latest question, this also has a SQL injection security issue - hope you plan to fix all of these. Don't expose your system users to security risk!)

Answer (score 1):

Use the " ' " if $b is a string

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO products
            SELECT * FROM item_code WHERE code ='". $b. " '";
```

otherwise user the below code

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO products
            SELECT * FROM item_code WHERE code =". $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO produtcs (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   item_code
WHERE code = $b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO products
            SELECT * FROM item_code WHERE code ='". $b. " '";
```

because the $b is not the string so you have to use like above